# How to use list in "docker's run -e options"?

Tags: docker

I downloaded my spring boot project from git on Amazon Linux2 OS and made it a docker image.

Then, I tried to use the **"docker run"** command to run the docker container with this image.

At this time, there are values in the form of an array among the environmental variables I need, and other **"docker run options"** worked well, but there was a problem with the values in this form of an array.

```
// Command 1
docker run -itd --name example_container -e DDL_AUTO={update,create,validate} -p 80:8080 example_image
```

In command 1's case, ***docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.*** error occured.

```
// Command 2 (put space between update, create, validate)
docker run -itd --name example_container -e DDL_AUTO={update, create, validate} -p 80:8080 example_image
```

In command 2's case, ***docker: invalid reference format.*** error occured.

Is there a way to put list optionally in this command format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put quotes around the environment variable value, since it contains characters the shell would otherwise interpret.  Try:

```sh
docker run -itd --name example_container -e DDL_AUTO="{update,create,validate}" -p 80:8080 example_image
```

Comment: Your answer is perfectly fit to me! Thank you so much... 
But, I have more question about your answer.
What does that command "--rm busybox ash" mean??

Comment: Delete the container after the command succeeded. Do mark the answer as it resolved your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your additional answer! I marked you answer for my question.